# Adding external HTML CSS and Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I created a cookie banner with some HTML, CSS and Javascript.
My question is how can I add these files within Wordpress to make the banner works on the whole site?
I know I could just use a Wordpress plugin to generate a cookie banner, but I was wondering if it was possible to integrate my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the following methods:

1. You may use the plugin "**Header and Footer**" (This plugin have different TABS like html, CSS, JavaScript) and add your whole in this plugin. So Your code work in whole WordPress website.
2. First, you need to install and activate the SyntaxHighlighter Evolved plugin. For more details, see our step by step guide on how to install a WordPress plugin.
   Upon activation, you can go ahead and edit the blog post where you want to display the code.